# How does a "random page" option help an application to succeed?

Tags: website-design, interaction-design

Some documentation applications, particularly wikis (including, of course, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page)) have a **Random Page** function.

My question is - how important and useful is that? Is there any objective data available on how that affects the success of an application?

Comment: I think it's just there for fun, and sometimes fun can add to the value of a learning-centric/knowledge-sharing app like a wiki. Not sure how you'd create objective data about it, though. Measure the GPA of students who only read random pages on wikipedia vs. those that didn't? ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following items make a random button *more useful*:

- The items are independent - i.e. are "consumed" individually
- Their relevance doesn't vary by orders of magnitude (averaged over users)
- casual exploration is a typical use case (is associated with *leisure time*)

Typical items are:

- encyclopaedias (including the dead tree editions)
- funny image / video collections
- Comics without a strong storyline
- Song lyrics
- Tip of the day

Answer (score 9):

I don't have any data, but surely it depends on the application.

Wikipedia, being an encyclopaedia, has a "user mode" of "browsing" (if you like) where a user will be using the site in an effectively random mode just following links that take their fancy. In this mode then a "show me a random page" function has real utility.

If however, I was using the site to find some specific piece of information then such a function would be useless and were I to actually click it counter productive.

So if your application has this "browsing" mode then a random function might be useful. I think you'd need to get some usage data to see if that's a valid model.

As an aside Stack Exchange might benefit from such a "Random Question" function to show a random unanswered question. In fact it has already been suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5551/59303)

Comment: nice answer; I gave you +1 for the incorporation in Stack Exchange... long overdue, I think.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much data you have to present. With [tv-tropes](http://tvtropes.org), it's a beautiful option because there is way too much data to navigate through in a meaningful way, while random browsing usually brings up something interesting.

Comment: yes, so in this sense just like Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, it all depends on context.  If appropriate, a "Random" button adds a nice element of playfulness to the website.  If inappropriate, it will distract and confuse.

Perhaps the most famous one is Google's **I'm Feeling Lucky** button.  FWIW, I have never used it, but I have used "random" button on other websites before (can't recall which, sorry) where discovery or learning is involved.

Comment: nice answer, but I thought Google's I'm Feeling Lucky (which I almost never use) took you to a predictable (the most popular?) site - not a random one.

Comment: yes, it is the first result: http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2007/11/im-feeling-lucky.html

Comment: And, in related reading: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/07/googles-number-one-ui-mistake.html :-)