# How to display a list of videos like YouTube?

Tags: navigation, lists

I'm trying to find a nice way to display a list of video's in a way that'll allow the user at a quick glance get insight to the video's and easily let them navigate through the list of video's without much effort. e.g., keep them on the site and encourage viewing of videos.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You stated that you want something like YouTube.  Then why don’t you do it just like YouTube?  If YouTube’s way is not suitable in your case, you should state why; then the question probably becomes much more interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the obvious simple list of screenshot/thumbnail with a snappy description by the side (or underneath) one thing that might work in this case is the [Random item button](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/2407/60).

It has to be said that You Tube's model is quite good with the list of related videos beside the current one to encourage further browsing.

I think that one of the reasons You Tube took off is that their UI is very intuitive. Click image to play video, click another image to play another and so on.

Comment: There's a few things I'll add in addition to this. e.g., automatic pagination like the New Twitter UI has and other features.